# Error with grub and linux-image that can't fix

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 64-bit, grub-efi

[image: linux-image 5.3.0.26 and 28 error]
[grub-pc error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHpNr.png)

I'm a fairly new linux user that installed a dual boot Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver)/windows 10 Home.

After messing around a bit with the configuration of the grub to change the wallpaper, I found myself having some errors that I have searched for solutions online with no success.
As you can see on the screenshots, I have errors on the linux-image 26 and 28 and grub-pc as well. I have tried the apt-get/dpkg solutions, tried to fix the grub and other solutions that I saw online but none worked.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Looks like you installed at least one GRUB theme (Tela). Try uninstalling it.

Comment: Problem is that I can't work on the grub because anytime that I try, I got the grub-pc error and I don't know how to go around it. I have tried every solution online but as soon as I reach that grub error, can't continue to follow the instructions.

Comment: Then you have two options: Look up how to edit your GRUB changes from a LiveUSB's "Try Ubuntu" environment, or else backup your data and reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the next command to find files containing `GRUB_THEME` keyword:

```
sudo grep -r GRUB_THEME /etc/* --color
```

In my case it found it in `/etc/grub.d/00_header` file.

It says `Sourcing file '/etc/default/grub'`, then `Generating grub configuration file ...`. Based on that file and `/etc/grub.d/*` files it generates `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file which is used to boot an OS.

Comment: I have checked my grub file and it is like you said. Other thing, I can't find the customizer on my pc and when I try to install it, I get stuck at the grub/linux image errors.

Comment: Tried to configure my VPN through the terminal and couldn't do to the same grub/linux errors, so it seems that I can't do much until this get fixed. Maybe resetting Ubuntu? All the threads online about resetting ubuntu aren't about ubuntu on dual boot, do you reckon that is the same method?

Comment: Try to find it using `sudo grep -r GRUB_THEME /etc/* --color` command. In my case it points to `/etc/grub.d/00_header` file.